# Запрос выдает ошибку "Identifier does not conform to RedBeanPHP security policies". Как совместить findLike + LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, redbeanphp

подскажите как корректно совместить findLike + LIKE в один запрос:

```
$fb = R::findLike('feedbacks', ['id' => $_SESSION['ids'], 'type' => 'd', 'text LIKE %'.$_POST["wrd"].'%']);
```

где:

- $_SESSION['ids'] - массив id
- $_POST["wrd"] - запрос для поиска

Задача отобразить все записи с id из массива с типом d и в text есть совпадение с введенным поисковым запросом

сейчас это выводит ошибку "Identifier does not conform to RedBeanPHP security policies"

RedBeanPHP\Finder->findLike('feedbacks', Array, '')

пробовал вариацию типа:

```
$fb = R::findLike('feedbacks', ['id' => $_SESSION['ids'], 'type' => 'd'], 'WHERE text LIKE ? %'.$_POST["wrd"].'%');
```

но тоже ошибка, но другая:

"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters trace"

RedBeanPHP\Finder->findLike('feedbacks', Array, 'WHERE text LIKE...')

Пробую такой вариант:

```
$fb = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `feedbacks` WHERE `type` = ? AND `text` LIKE ? AND `id` IN('.implode(",", $_SESSION["ids"]).')', ['d', '%'.$_POST["wrd"].'%'] );
```

Ошибку не выдает, но в блоке пусто без значений, добавляю:

```
$fb = R::convertToBeans('fb', $fb);
```

И работает запрос...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким вариантом, использовать функции запросов SQL - метод getAll() вернёт массив данных:

```
$fb = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `feedbacks` WHERE `type` = ? AND `text` LIKE ? AND `id` IN('.implode(",", $_SESSION["ids"]).')', ['d', '%'.$_POST["wrd"].'%'] );
```

Где IN позволяет определить, совпадает ли значение id со значением в списке, a из массива ids делаем список (через запятую) с помощью implode:

```
IN('.implode(",", $_SESSION["ids"]).')
```

Далее, добавляю конвертацию массива записей в бины:

```
$fb = R::convertToBeans('fb', $fb);
```

И работает запрос. Задача была с помощью RedbeanPHP отобразить все записи с id из массива, с типом d, и в text есть совпадение с введенным поисковым запросом

```
$fb = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `feedbacks` WHERE `type` = ? AND `text` LIKE ? AND `id` IN('.implode(",", $_SESSION["ids"]).')', ['d', '%'.$_POST["wrd"].'%'] );
$fb = R::convertToBeans('fb', $fb);
```